# Ng-Include comments out on Controller compile

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, gruntjs

i'm creating a angular app, and have an strange issue.

This is my controller:

```
angular.module('clientApp')
.controller('AdminCtrl', function ($scope) {


});
```

This is my view:

```
    <div class="admin" ng-controller="AdminCtrl">
      <div ng-include="'/views/partials/header-admin.html'"></div>
      <p>This is the admin view.</p>
    </div>
```

the thing is when i run the app the ng-include appears comment out:

```
<!-- ngInclude: '/views/partials/header-admin.html' -->
```

but if i remove the ng-controller of my view it renders the ng-include without problems:

```
 <div class="admin" >
    <div ng-include="'/views/partials/header-admin.html'"></div>
    <p>This is the admin view.</p>
</div>
```

html:

```
<div ng-include="'/views/partials/header-admin.html'" class="ng-scope"><header class="ng-scope">
    <div class="logo">
    <div class="user-preferences"></div>
</div></header>
<nav class="left-nav ng-scope">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <a href="#">Dashboard</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">Temas (Materias)</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">Sitios</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">Grupos</a>
        </li><!-- 
        <li>
            <a href="#">Dashboard</a>
        </li> -->
    </ul>
</nav></div>
```

Comment: Is that your whole html? (head, body)

Comment: Create a plunker demo that replicates this

Comment: No , is just the output for that view

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you have an error in your partial view code. You can't have a ng-include pointing to the same file:

```
<div ng-include="'/views/partials/header-admin.html'" class="ng-scope"><header class="ng-scope">
```

if you do that you have to recive some error like:

[image]

because you create a infinite bucle with the includes files, so the first thing that you have to do is remove the include in your partial file. I think this should not have any more problem!